# How to run my own shell script inside user data in ec2 instance

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, shell, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have a shell script which copies files from an s3 bucket and then runs a python script and later deletes the file which was copied.
this file panorama.sh is in the /home/ubuntu directory of my ec2 instance.
I have modified my user data of the ec2 instance as follows

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//
Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

#cloud-config
cloud_final_modules:
- [scripts-user, always]

--//
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"

#!/bin/sh
sh ./panorama.sh
```

However this does not seem to work as when i check my cloud watch log in /var/log/cloud-init-output.log  im getting this in the end

sh: 0: Can't open ./panorama.sh
Cloud-init v. 20.4.1-0ubuntu1~18.04.1 running 'modules:final' at Thu, 11 Mar 2021 08:31:38 +0000. Up 17.05 seconds.
2021-03-11 08:31:38,684 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2021-03-11 08:31:38,684 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python$

I tried putting ls in the user data to see what are the files in the current directory. It seems to be in the same working directory (/home/ubuntu). So why is it not able to find my shell script and execute it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User data does not execute in `/home/ubuntu`, but in root `/`. So you have to change to `/home/ubuntu` first:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /home/ubuntu
sh ./panorama.sh
```

Comment: Thank you this seems to work. However, one of my commands in the shell script involves copying files from s3 bucket to the instance. This command does not seem to execute and throws the following error in the log 'fatal error: Unable to locate credentials' What do i do?